# Логика операции "Остаток от деления" в СИ

Tags: c

```
 с = a % b
```

Верно ли я понимаю, что всегда, когда `a<b`, переменная `c` будет равняться `a`?

Пример:

```
c = 3 % 8 /// = 3
```

Проверка компилятором простых случаев показала, что всё так и есть, но не всплывут ли подводные камни в более сложных случаях/примерах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не верно. `-25 % 8` равно `-1`. Как видите, выполняется `a < b`, но результат не равен `a`.

Если вы подразумевали только неотрицательные операнды (такие детали стоит оговаривать в вопросе), то да, если `a < b`, то `a % b` будет всегда равно именно `a`.

Это гарантию можно расширить: благодаря тому, что целочисленное деление в современном С и С++ гарантированно выполняется с округлением к нулю, из `abs(a) < abs(b)` следует, что `a % b` равно `a`.